# Where is provided an official download of Windows 8.1 Core in Spanish?

Tags: windows, download, windows-8.1, iso-image, msdn

### Scenario

I would like to perform an unatended installation of **Windows 8.1** then integrate some custom elements like drivers and other files. I require the ISO of **Windows 8.1** in my language but I can't find it in Google or Torrent neither Technet/MSDN.

### Problem

I need the `Windows 8.1 Core edition x64 Spanish`, not the Pro edition.

### Question

Where I could download it?.

### Research

Searching information in `MSDN` about the ISO that I require I've seen that MSDN distributes a single DVD for the Core edition and a single DVD for the Pro edition for English people, but seems that for the Spanish region the Core edition is distributen in a DVD together with the Pro edition? Someone could explain that? (Maybe I'm wrong but this seems what I've seen [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/securedownloads/hh442898#searchTerm=Windows%208.1&ProductFamilyId=0&Languages=es&Architectures=x64&ProductFamilyIds=524&FileExtensions=.iso&PageSize=10&PageIndex=0&FileId=0) in MSDN ) so I think that the ISO file that I require which contains the Core edition is this?:

> Windows 8.1 (multiple editions) (x64) - DVD (Spanish)
>
> This file contains both Windows 8.1 and Windows 8.1 Pro. Please refer
>   to your product keys to determine which products are included with
>   your subscription.
>
> File Name: es_windows_8_1_x64_dvd_2707379.iso
>
> Languages: Spanish
>
> SHA1: 08C6B43ED6C96E7F98DAED9D13308E536B6D1481

Where I can direct download legally (but for free) that ISO, or the ISO in my language that only contains the Core edition?

Comment: The websites you have listed are the legal method.  There isn't any other way

Comment: Then if a person purchases a better edition of Windows 8.1 product and him would like to reverse to the Core edition him needs to pay for a ridiculous year subscription in MSDN to download a single file? or my real situation which is that I only want to download the evaluation of windows 8.1 Core in spanish then just I can't? ...how could be possibly that?

Comment: If you purchase a digital retail license then there is a way to get an .iso in a digital format  But you have MSDN licenses, or it appears you do, honestly not all that clear.

Comment: I have not an MSDN subscription, I only wanted to download the evaluation of Windows 8.1 Core edition x64 in spanish, if that could be possibly. thanks for comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only the Enterprise version is available for evaluation.

You can get it here (including in Spanish): http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/hh699156.aspx

Additionally, the Enterprise version is the only version intended to be used for making images to be distributed to network computers.